# Issue with .checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am helping someone fix their plain javascript highlight-when-checked

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/KSezJ/)

If you click yes or no, you will see it breaks and makes an unchecked row highlighted.

I know I could rewrite it in jQuery, but I would REALLY like to know what makes it fail

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're adding the classname every time. So if you change between yes/no 5 times, item3 will have classname `radio-item myclass myclass myclass myclass myclass`. So in your `replace` you need to make sure it's global (replacing every occurance of the search string)

**edit:**

This code is adding the classname without checking if it's there in the first place. Remember, you're looping *all* checkboxes, for every change on any of them.

```
if (inputArray[i].checked) {
    inputArray[i].parentNode.className += " myclass";
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan I've edited my answer to show you the code that's messing up.

Comment: If only there was some library that took care of things like this. I bet everyone would start using it, and we wouldn't have to deal with issues like this anymore.

Comment: @StefanKendall Well, the OP asked for a non-library answer. People might have their reasons for not using libraries...

Comment: @peirix: Some people have really bad ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some library functions I wrote some time ago:

```
function trim(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

function hasClassName(el, cName) {
    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}

function addClassName(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (!hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        el.className = trim(el.className + ' ' + cName);
    }
}

function removeClassName(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = trim(el.className.replace(re, ''));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Seems you are on his case anyway - I still want to see where my code is wrong.

Comment: Found it. - just needed a test for existence of myclass in the add